# What is the shortest code to write text/image to a HWND

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I don't need to have controls or anything, I just need to write something onto a HWND, either centred text or an image, that shows it has been rendered to. The actual use-case is I get passed a HWND at a point I'm not ready to deal with it, so I want to to display text on it like "this Window cannot be used", or a sad-face graphics, etc.

Nothing fancy, just raw hacky code but all you have is the HWND to work with, in pure Win32.

Comment: You need to get an `HDC`. Then you are good to go. If this is displayed on the screen then you need to make sure that your code runs as part of the WM_PAINT handler. If you want a good answer you ought to specify more details, especially how you come by this `HWND`.

Comment: That's kind of the point, it just gets given me from an external library, which will also tell me when to repaint (it abstracts the winProc internally). I'm rusty on Win32 so just really all I need is someone expert to bash out a Hello World equivalent :)

Comment: See also, `TextOut` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: You ought to accept one of your answers. The question is, which one!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
char * text = "this Window cannot be used";
DrawTextA(hdc, text, strlen(text), &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
ReleaseDC(hdc);
```

You might want to select a different font before you draw the text, but this will get you started.

Answer (score 8):

That's actually fairly straightforward.

```
// Grab the window dimensions.
RECT bounds;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &bounds);

// Grab a DC to draw with.
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

// The money shot!
DrawText(hdc, messageText, -1, &bounds, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

// Now give back the borrowed DC.
ReleaseDC(hdc);
```

Comment: ...but you get the up-vote. Wish I could mark you both as answered!